# ldap_bind PHP authentication

Tags: php

I am trying to authenticate users against Active Directory with PHP for access to a web page.

ldap_bind works fine for users who are setup with "Logon Workstations" set to "All computers" in Active Directory but not for users who are setup with their computer name in "The following computers" option which only allows them to log on to their own pc.

Is there a way to just authenticate if the users username/password combination are correct and not have it check the computers they can log on to?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to allow for manual authentication for users who are not automatically logged in.

I have something similar to this setup on my company's intranet, where if a user is not automatically authenticated they are presented with a login form that submits to a controller that uses the [adLDAP library](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/) to pass the username and password to the LDAP server for authentication.